# Jsonify response data with backslash

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a flask API that sends response in json format

```
rep = {'application_id': 32657, 'business_rules_id': 20} # a python dictionary
rep_json = json.dumps(rep, cls=CustomizedEncoder) # converts to a json format string
return jsonify(rep_json), 200 . #return the flask response (with headers etc)
```

I can see the flask response body data and the response is something like:

```
b'"{\\"application_id\\": 32567, \\"business_rules_id\\": 20}"\n'
```

or in postman body

```
"{\"application_id\": 32567, \"business_rules_id\": 20}
```

Should i get a response in JSON format (without the backslash)? I guess the reason is that json.dumps dump the string to json once then jsonify dump it a second time which cause the double quote to be escaped.

The reason that I need to run the following is because i need a customized encoder which jsonify probably does not support.

```
rep_json = json.dumps(rep, cls=CustomizedEncoder)
```

My other solution is to dumps then loads but which make it looks redudant. Is there a different approach to use a customized encoder while return a Flask response?

This is another way that I tried but looks weird

```
rep = {'application_id': 32657, 'business_rules_id': 20} # a python dictionary
rep_json = json.dumps(rep, cls=CustomizedEncoder) # converts to a json format string
return jsonify(json.loads(rep_json)), 200 . #return the flask response (with headers etc)
```

Comment: You're converting the result twice to json - by `json.dumps` and later by `jsonify`, hence the additional escaping. You need only `jsonify`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply h4z3. anyway to use jsonify with a customized encoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your app to use a customer encoder with `app.json_encoder = CustomizedEncoder`

https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.app.Flask.json_encoder